# testing shiny, runApp error, can not find path

Tags: shiny

I have taken the code from http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/build.html to test building a shiny app myself.

I have created a folder called 'Shiny' and made a project in R with this folder. Inside this project I have a folder called 'shiny_app' containing the `ui.R` and `server.R` files.

When I run `runApp("/shiny_app")`, I get the following error

`Error in shinyAppDir(x) : 
  No Shiny application exists at the path "/shiny_app"`

I have not changed the code from the website so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Can anyone advise? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Check Working directory `setwd("C:/Users/DND/Desktop/your folder")`

**2)** Remove the forward slash, I don't think it is necessary `runApp("shiny_app", launch.browser = T)`